# How form values are persisted after postback?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

After i populate some form(asp.net mvc) and press submit button after that form values are the same as before submit the form and i do not repopulate input fields from backend code. Can explain me how values are persisted cross request(and that values are not repopulated)?

Comment: This topic maybe help you find anwser.

[How does MVC populate the model when data is posted back][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976307/how-does-mvc-populate-the-model-when-data-is-posted-back

Comment: Please show controller code.

Comment: I read that question and related answers, but mystery is in place for me. I can understand that controller does not pass any model to view but inputs are updated and every input is represented in razor view with help of Html extensions as Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Name) for example .... and model is null but values are in place... what's just happening

Comment: [HttpGet]

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Person p)
        {
            return View();
        }

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are asking about how MVC moder binder works(parsing posted data on the server), the default Model binder, which was designed to effectively bind most model types, does a relatively simple and recursive logic for each property of the target model.

1 It determines whether the property is a simple type or complex type by checking the **property name**  are registered as a prefix. The prefix pattern is [ParentProperty].[Property]

2 Get the [ValueProviderResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.valueproviderresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) from the registered value providers for the property’s name.

3 If the property is a simple type, it tries to convert the property using the properties [TypeConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from the source value of type ***string*** to the  from the source value of type string to the ***target type***

4 Otherwise, the property is a complex type, so perform a recursive binding.

If you try to see the posted value the browser sends to the server, you could understand how to form data is sent, and get the idea. For reference, consult this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx